# Error while importing tensorflow in jupyter environment

Tags: tensorflow, import, jupyter

**Its repetitively showing this error while importing tensorflow**

I am using a separate environment in anaconda with jupyter installed.Can anyone help me solve this error

> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
> last)
> E:\Anaconda2\Library\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py
> in 
> 63   try:
> ---> 64     from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
> 65   # This try catch logic is because there is no bazel equivalent for py_extension.
>
> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 1 import os
> ----> 2 import tensorflow as tf
> 3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
> 4 import numpy as np
> 5 import pandas as pd
>
> E:\Anaconda2\Library\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_*init*_.py
> in 
> 39 import sys as _sys
> 40
> ---> 41 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
> 42 from tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader import LazyLoader as _LazyLoader
> 43
>
> E:\Anaconda2\Library\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python_*init*_.py
> in 
> 37 # go/tf-wildcard-import
> 38 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import,g-bad-import-order,g-import-not-at-top
> ---> 39 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
> 40
> 41 from tensorflow.python.eager import context
>
> E:\Anaconda2\Library\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py
> in 
> 81 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
> 82 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
> ---> 83   raise ImportError(msg)
> 84
> 85 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long
>
> ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "E:\Anaconda2\Library\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
> line 64, in 
> from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import * ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: How did you install Tensorflow?

Comment: what versions of tensorflow and python are you using?  Did you install tensorflow with pip or with conda?

Answer (score 0):

DLL load fail error is because either you have not installed  [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0) or your CPU does not support AVX2 instructions

There is a workaround either you have to compile Tensorflow from source or use google colaboratory to work. Follow the instructions mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows) to build Tensorflow from source.